# Как подключить Chai к IDE WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, webstorm

Выполнил:

```
npm install chai
```

Установил:

```
chai-DefinetlyTyped
```

Но при попытке выполнить assert, ловлю :

> chai is not defined

Код:

```
 var assert = chai.assert;
    assert.isOk('everything', 'everything is ok');
```

Или скрипт нужно непосредственно в браузере открывать, а не в IDE?

Comment: А вы его импортировали? `var chai = require('chai')`, etc? вообще-то у Вас runtime error, WebStorm здесь не при делах скорее всего

Comment: @lena, да, так работает. Спасибо.